# How to check which query has run frequently very frequently in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to understand some performance running behavior in the MongoDB.

I have set of collections and based on that we are running the daily jobs and accumulating data from different resources. There are multiple queries are used to retrieve the data from different collections.

In MongoDB, can I get the most frequently running queries and check the stats as we do in Postgres by using "pg_stat_statements".

Any leads will help.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer my self. In Mongo we can not get the stats for all the collection at time, but we can find the stats for each collection.

Reference : https://blog.mlab.com/2017/01/using-mongodb-indexstats-to-identify-and-remove-unused-indexes/